# How to make 9x9 grid in python and view in console not in GUI because I want to make a Soduko game?

Tags: python, sudoku

I want to make a Sudoku game using python and not play it in GUI but only in console. First how to make 9x9 grid without the help of GUI Tknter etc.

Comment: Can you not just `print()` the board and then use `input()` twice, once to get the cell to fill and a second time to get the number that the user wants to place in it?

Comment: Search with `python print ascii table` produces some possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use print statements, for suitable characters to make grid, may be something like this:

```
     |    |
     |    |
________________
     |    |
     |    |
________________
     |    |
     |    |
```

You can use escape sequences for easy handling of spacing, etc as bad alignment will make it look bad.
Then you need to put 'O' and 'X' in appropriate positions.  There are some formatting methods available in python to provide appropriate space padding to your characters so that yoir alignment doesn't get disturbed on adding characters. See https://pyformat.info for examples on padding/formatting.